# Simple username login with membership provider in Active Directory

Tags: .net, active-directory, asp.net-membership, activedirectorymembership

I use Active Directory for authentication through `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` in one of my ASP.Net projects.

I connect to it successfully with this LDAP connection string:

```
LDAP://server/DC=mydomain,DC=com
```

but two issues remain :

1. calling `Membership.GetUser("moravej")` returns Null whereas calling `Membership.GetUser("moravej@mydomain.com")` get a correct object. Is there anyway to solve this? I don't want to make the users to use their complete name when AD is transparent to them. Also I prefer not to change my codes to concatenate `@mydomain.com` to entered values (because of lots of changes I need)
2. I want the membership to be able to use all AD users for login. (it does it in this case) but I want to all the users that will be created by my application goto a CRM OU. If I set the connection string to `LDAP://server/OU=CRM,DC=mydomain,DC=com` it returns null when I call `Membership.GetUser()` for users that are not in this OU.

Is there any way to solve these issues?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How you are "connect to it successfully" without username(CN) and password?

Comment: I set the username and password in provider settings (connectionUsername and connectionPassword)...be sure about successful connection :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to this page here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650308.aspx), you can define to use the `SAMAccountName` for your logon - with some config:

> *The default configuration for the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider
>   uses User Principal Names (UPNs) for name mapping as shown in the
>   following example.*
>
> ```
> attributeMapUsername="userPrincipalName"
> ```
>
> *Because of this, all user names must have the format UserName@DomainName; for example: mary@testdomain.com or steve@testdomain.com.*

But you can change that - see the paragraph below:

> *You can change the name mapping so that it uses simple user name format by setting the following attribute in the Membership Provider
>   configuration in the Web.config file.*
>
> ```
> attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"
> ```
>
> *With this configuration, you can use simple user names, for example: Mary or Steve.*

That appears to be what you're looking for - right?

So in your `web.config`, you should have a configuration entry something like this (of course - use **your** connection string names etc. - this is just a sample!)

```
<system.web>
<membership defaultProvider="MyADMembershipProvider">
   <providers>
      <add name="MyADMembershipProvider"
           type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider,
                 System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
                 PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
           connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
           attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName"/>  <== this is the magic to turn ON
  </providers>
</membership>
</system.web>
```

For problem #2: if you want **all** users, then set your connection string for the membership provider to `LDAP://server/DC=mydomain,DC=com` so that it connects to the domain root of your AD domain.

Comment: greate marc! the magic works for the first problem. But for the second problem the mentioned connection string is ok for retrieval but I want to put all my users inside CRM organization unit(OU). If I set the mentioned connection string , all the new users will be created in root which is disaster!

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej: can't you handle an `OnUserBeingCreated` event or something, to set the OU where the new user goes into?? I don't see any other way to retrieve **all** users ....

Comment: I couldn't find something like that. I hoped to find a LDAP connection string hack. BTW thanks for your magic again :-)

Comment: @MahmoudMoravej: sounds like a perfect follow-up question here on StackOverflow - I'm sure others have already had the same problem (and hopefully have a solution, too!)